# Set Navigation Bar / Action Bar color from within the App (Android)

Tags: java, android, colors, action

I have set up an Activity with one **EditText** and one **Button** and I'm trying do the following thing: the user types a color in hexadecimal in the EditText, presses the Button and then the NavBar/ActionBar changes its color to the typed value.

The only way for changing those within the app that I found was to change the Style of the NavBar/ActionBar to a premade one, but I'd like to be able to set it to a custom color.

```
public class VisualTweaks extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visual_tweaks);

        Button colorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countButton);
        EditText colorEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.colorEditText);

        colorButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.navigationbar_color));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick fix that i found for the actionBar :

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar;

 actionBar = getActionBar(); 
 ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#93E9FA"));     
 actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

as u same colorDrawable use for your navigation bar also